# RSpec stub deprecation warning for stub method of another library

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rspec

I have a spec that runs without issues except when I try to run single `it` blocks. In this case I get a `Failure/Error: before(:context)` with the explanation:

> The use of doubles or partial doubles from rspec-mocks outside of the
>   per-test lifecycle is not supported. Using `stub` from rspec-mocks'
>   old `:should` syntax without explicitly enabling the syntax is
>   deprecated. Use the new `:expect` syntax or explicitly enable
>   `:should` instead.

The issue is that I don't use the `rspec-mocks` `stub` method but the one defined by `dry-container`:

- https://dry-rb.org/gems/dry-container/testing/
- https://github.com/dry-rb/dry-container/blob/8fc95d0fe3a2f2c779bc4c3238265cb45353d245/lib/dry/container/stub.rb#L12

Like so:

```
require 'dry/container/stub'

before { FooContainer.enable_stubs! }

before(:context) { FooContainer.stub 'foo.key', stubbed_operation }

after(:context) { FooContainer.unstub 'foo.key' }
```

Is there a way to disable this RSpec behaviour without enabling the old `rspec-mocks` syntax?

---

```
rspec --version
RSpec 3.8
  - rspec-core 3.8.0
  - rspec-expectations 3.8.2
  - rspec-mocks 3.8.0
  - rspec-rails 3.8.2
  - rspec-support 3.8.0


rails -v
Rails 5.2.2.1

ruby -v
ruby 2.6.2p47 (2019-03-13 revision 67232) [x86_64-linux]

dry-container (0.6.0)
```

Comment: did this start recently?  has your Gemfile.lock changed ?

Comment: @lacostenycoder I added the offending code today so yes it has started recently but I did not change my `Gemfile.lock` in the meantime. I edited my question with relevant gem versions.

Comment: Is there anything helpful here?  https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/blob/7dc2a431101172d31b780458eb168e05d20fb3aa/lib/rspec/mocks/configuration.rb

Comment: @lacostenycoder basically the config options which I don't want to change because I want to be warned in other places. I've found a workaround tough which only costs a little bit of performance. Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is, that you enabled the stub in the `before(:each)` block not within the `before(:context)` block, which is execuded before the `before(:each)` block. At this point the `stub` method from `dry-container` is unknown to rspec/ruby and therefore it tries to use the default `stub` method from `rspec-mock`.

```
require 'dry/container/stub'

before(:context) { FooContainer.enable_stubs! }
before(:context) { FooContainer.stub 'foo.key', stubbed_operation }

# or better
before(:context) do
  FooContainer.enable_stubs!
  FooContainer.stub 'foo.key', stubbed_operation
end

after(:context) { FooContainer.unstub 'foo.key' }

context "my context" do
  it "my test" do
    ...
  end
end
```

From the [dry-container testing documentation](https://dry-rb.org/gems/dry-container/testing/)

```
# before stub you need to enable stubs for specific container
container.enable_stubs!
container.stub(:redis, "Stubbed redis instance")
```

Comment: I think you need to swap `before(:each)` with `before(:context)` in your first paragraph since the workaround I use now uses `before`/ `before(:each)` instead of  `before(:context)`.

Comment: @wintersolutions my indent was, to replied to your question (not to your workaround). Anyway, the point is you need to call `.enable_stubs!` before you can use `.stub` from `dry-container`. It depends on your setup, if you like to do this within a `before(:context)` or a `before(:each) ` block.

Comment: Yep I understand now and agree 100%. Grüße

Answer (score 1):

I've found a workaround now if I use:

```
before { FooContainer.stub 'foo.key', stubbed_operation }

after { FooContainer.unstub 'foo.key' }
```

instead of:

```
before(:context) { FooContainer.stub 'foo.key', stubbed_operation }

after(:context) { FooContainer.unstub 'foo.key' }
```

It works. The only drawback I can see is that it will cost a little performance and that it could break in the future.